# Criar tabela em javascript a partir de um array dinâmico

Tags: javascript, html, dom, table

Tenho um array dinâmico onde são adicionados dados a partir de um formulário, porém preciso apresentar os dados em uma `table`  HTML. Exemplo:

HTML/CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Table</title>
<style>
    body {
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    display: block;
}

button {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

#table {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
        
    <div id="tabela">
        <button>Get</button>

        <div>
           <table id="table">
             
                <thead id="thHeader">
                    <tr id="headerhed">                                    
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Produto</th>
                    <th>Cor</th>                                               
                      </tr>                                                                 
                  </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
              
            </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
        </div>

      
    <script src="JS/js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var conteudo = ["Cód001", "Produto001", "Cor001", "Cód002", "Produto002", "Cor002"]

conteudo.forEach(e => {
  var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody')

  var td = document.createElement('td')

  tbody.appendChild(td)

  td.innerText = e

})
```

Resultado:
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOX6R.png)

Porém preciso que até o índice 2 do array crie outra linha com o conteúdo restante, por exemplo:

Resultado esperado:

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svkWe.png)

Answer (score -2):

Eu copiei seu código,e editei apenas o arquivo JavaScript.

Como você parece ser iniciante, fiz um código mais simples, que você pode refatorar depois de entender a lógica dele.

Pra resolver sua pergunta, você precisa apenas de um array de objetos, onde cada objeto vai ser um produto, assim, quando o forEach mudar de objeto, ele começa na próxima linha da tabela.

```js
const conteudo = [{ cod: 'Cód001', prod: 'Produto001', cor: 'Cor001' }, 
  { cod: 'Cód002', prod: 'Produto002', cor: 'Cor002' },
  { cod: 'Cód003', prod: 'Produto003', cor: 'Cor003' }];

conteudo.forEach(e => {
  const tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
  
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  const tdCod = document.createElement('td');
  const tdProd = document.createElement('td');
  const tdCor = document.createElement('td');

  tdCod.innerText = e.cod;
  tdProd.innerText = e.prod;
  tdCor.innerText = e.cor;
  
  tr.appendChild(tdCod);
  tr.appendChild(tdProd);
  tr.appendChild(tdCor);

  tbody.appendChild(tr);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Table</title>
<style>
    body {
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    display: block;
}

button {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

#table {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>     
  <div id="tabela">
    <button>Get</button>
    <div>
      <table id="table">   
        <thead id="thHeader">
          <tr id="headerhed">                                    
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>Cor</th>                                               
          </tr>                                                                 
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">    
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="JS/js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show! 

Esse array é sempre acrescentado com dados do firestore, ou seja, ele retorna dados de uma coleção do firestore. Preciso retirar os obejtos correspodentes de lá, no seu devido objeto.